# Struct containing embedded slice of struct

Tags: go, struct, constructor

I have this code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type foo struct {
    a int
    b bool
}

type foos []foo

type bar struct {
    foos
}

func newBar() *bar {
    b := &bar{
        foos: make([]foo, 3, 3),
    }
    for _, foo := range b.foos {
        // didn't set b to true
        foo.b = true
    }
    return b
}

func main() {
    b := newBar()
    fmt.Println(b)
    // set b to true
    b.foos[0].b = true
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pDUaN8wRUPU)

As you can see I want to initialize `bar` using constructor `newBar()` but I want the embed type foo.b is initialize with non zero value so I initialize with for range statement but it didn't work as intended, the `foo.b` is still false, all of them. As comparison in the main function using this code `b.foos[0].b = true` it work. So whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Omg, I just realized this after posting this question, it's because variable `slot` is local to `for loop`. So the solution is:

```
for i, _ := range b.foos {
    // now b is set to true
    b.foos[i].b = true
}
```

Comment: Yes. In the case `for _, foo := range b.foos {`, each item in `b.foos` gets copied to `foo`, so changing `foo` will not be reflected in `b.foos`. The solution you suggest in your answer fixes it by referencing the original instances, without copying. If however `b.foos` were a slice of pointers to `foo` ( `[]*foo` ), the pointer would have been copied but not the original value, so the `for _, foo := range b.foos {` would have worked as expected, given that you had first allocated each item.